# Php Form - Stop Script running untill submit is clicked

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I have made a simple form which I am going to ask student to complete online.

it consists of a number of fields which will be passed into a mysql database. The form is working fine but the only problem is when I load the page for the first time it tries to submit nothing(as all the fields are empty) to the database and an error comes up which I have set which says you have not completed the required fields

How I can get the script part of my page to run only when the submit button is clicked?

Here is my code

```
    <! Code to check that the user has logged into to view this page !>
<?php
Code to check for session here
?>
<!Connection details for connecting to mysql database!>
<?php
Info for connection to database
 }

//Select which database you want to connect to
Code to select database here
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Op Tech Database - Add Record</title>
</head>
<!Code to Create drop down menu's!>
<?php
//Code for collectiing values for Student Names drop down drop
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT studentID, studentName FROM students");
$options1="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $id=$row["studentID"];
    $first=$row["studentName"];

    $options1.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$first\">".$first.'</option>';
    }

//Code for getting tutors names in drop down list
$result2=mysql_query("SELECT staffID, tutorName FROM staff");

$options2="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

    $id=$row["staffID"];
    $first=$row["tutorName"];

    $options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$first\">".$first.'</option>';
}
  ?>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex1.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />
<!Create HTML elements!>
<form name="myform" form method="post">
  <h1 align="center"><a href="both.php"><img src="colour_logo_400.jpg" alt="University Logo" width="400" height="185" /></a></h1>
  <h1 align="center">Dental Hygiene Operative Technique Database</h1>
  <h2 align="center">Welcome to the Dental Hygiene Operative Technique Database v1</h2>
  <p align="left">Student Name</p>
  <p align="left">

   <! Drop Down Menu to get student names from database !>
   <SELECT NAME=studentName >
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?php 

 echo $options1
 ?>
</SELECT>  
  <p align="left">Tutor Name  
  <p align="left"> 

  <! Drop Down Menu to get tutor names from database !>
  <select name=tutorName>
    <option value=0>

      <?php echo $options2 ?> </option> 
  </select>
  <p align="left">

<p align="left"><br>


   Procedure
  <input type="text" name="procedure"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['procedure'])) echo $_POST['procedure'];?>" />
<p align="left">
<br>
<SELECT NAME=grade id=grade>
        <OPTION VALUE="">Grade
        <OPTION VALUE="N" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "N") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>N</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="B" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "B") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>B</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="C" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "C") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>C</option>
        </SELECT>
        <br>
<br>
          Student Reflection:<br>
      <textarea name="studentReflection" cols="100" rows="5"><?php if(isset($_POST['studentReflection'])) echo $_POST['studentReflection'];?></textarea>
  <p align="left">
<p align="left">
<p align="left">
  <p align="left">
      <SELECT NAME=professionalism>
          <OPTION VALUE="">Professionalism
          <OPTION VALUE="U" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "U") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="S" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "S") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>S</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="E" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "E") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        </SELECT>
        </SELECT>
      <SELECT NAME=communication>
        <OPTION VALUE="">Communication
        <OPTION VALUE="U" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "U") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="S" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "S") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>S</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="E" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "E") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        </SELECT>

        Alert:
        <input type="checkbox" value="YES" name="alert" >  
      <br>

<br>
      Tutor Comments:<br>
      <textarea name="tutorComments" cols="100" rows="5"><?php if(isset($_POST['tutorComments'])) echo $_POST['tutorComments'];?></textarea>
  <p align="left">

      <input type="submit" value="Update Database"  /> 

  <input type='button' value='Logout' onClick="window.location.href='http://138.253.2.72/php_sandbox/optech/dh/current/14june/logout.php'">  
  <p align="left">

</FORM>
<p>  <a href="both.php">Enter another procedure </a>
<p>
  <?php
//Error Message to display if all the correct fields are not completed.
$errorMessage = "This is the standard error message";

$options1 = $_POST['studentName'];
$options2 = $_POST['tutorName'];
$procedure = $_POST['procedure'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$studentReflection = $_POST['studentReflection'];
$professionalism = $_POST['professionalism'];
$communication = $_POST['communication'];
$tutorComments = $_POST ['tutorComments'];

if(empty($_POST['alert']))
{
$_POST['alert'] = "NO";
}
$alert = $_POST['alert'] ;

//Code to check that the Student Name field is completed
if(empty($_POST['studentName'])) 
{
echo "You have not selected a student. Please go back and do so!";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Tutor Name field is completed
if(empty($_POST['tutorName'] ))
{
echo "You did not select a tutor name. Please go back and select your name from the tutors list";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Procedure field is completed
if(empty($_POST['procedure'] ))
{
echo  "You did not select a procedure. Please go back and enter the name of the procedure which you undertook";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Grade field is completed
if(empty($_POST['grade'] ))
{
echo "You did not select a grade. Please go back and select your grade from the drop down list";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Student Reflection field is completed
if(empty($_POST['studentReflection'] ))
{
echo "The student did not enter any comments for this procedure. Student reflection is required for each procedure. Please go back and enter any comments";
exit();
}
//Code to check if the tick box is checked that the tutor comment is entered
if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComments']) && isset($_POST['alert']) ){
    echo "You must enter a comment on the student if you tick the alert box";
    exit();
}

//Code to connect to the database
Database connect code here


$query= "INSERT INTO entry (entryID, studentName , tutorName , procedureName , grade , studentReflection , tutorComments,  professionalism , communication , alert  ) VALUES ('NULL', '".$options1."' , '".$options2." ' , '".$procedure."' , '".$grade."' , '".$studentReflection."', '".$tutorComments."' , '".$professionalism."' , '".$communication."' , '".$alert."'  )";


mysql_query($query) or die ('Error : Something fucked up' .mysql_error());


echo "The Database Has been updated. Thanks " ;
?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you could show your code...?

Answer (score 2):

If the form posts the data you would use something like

```
If($_POST){}
```

And place your code within the curly braces, this detects if any data is being sent to the page before processing it. But without seeing your code I can't tell you much else.

Answer (score 2):

Run the script on POST requests only:

```
if ( 'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
{
    // process the form data
    // print result
}
else
{
    // print form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missinterpreting PHP. You **can't stop the script** until the form is submited, since the whole script is run and the result is sent to the users browser. So, you need some mechanism to run only **certain parts** of the script.

In the form, insert a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" />
```

in your php code, before you try to get the values of the form and save it to the database, check:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {

    // your save code goes here

}
```

Comment: I tried this but don't think I was putting the code you suggested in the right area. I added the hidden field and then added the if statement just before the php gets the POST values. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, this should be correct. the end curly brace must be at the very end of the code (after `echo "The Database Has been updated. Thanks " ;`)

Comment: I have tried to add the if statement before this code 
$errorMessage = "This is the standard error message";

but am getting a syntax error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Answer (score 0):

You can give name & value to your submit button. 
Say `name= "submit" value ="submit"`

and put your all php code which you want to execute after button is clicked

```
if($_REQUEST['submit'] =='submit' && isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
  //php code
}
```

this will work fine to you

Comment: I have tried this suggestion but when I complete the form and click submit nothing happens.